# null Header httpclient android

Tags: android, eclipse, header, null

```
//more code
public void run()
          {
            DefaultHttpClient localDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try
            {
                Object localObject = localDefaultHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://ev5.playevo.com/_/Special:Register"));
              ((Header[]) null);
//more code
```

the last part gives me a this.

Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [ResponseHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) to do that.

Comment: The sad thing is I do not know how to implement that.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? I'm trying to fix an app that someone gave up on.

Comment: I may have figured it out but i have to fix a few other things to get it to launch. Once I do I will post my fix and select this answer.

Comment: A newer answer would be nice. There is no need to apologize. I'm just a little antsy about getting things done.